# click the {/0} icon?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slimscroll

Edit and add information to your business listing

After you’ve added and verified your business, you’ll be able to add a description for your business, hours of operation, and contact information.

To edit your information, click the {/0} icon in your dashboard, then click **Edit** next to the business you want to update.

what does {/0} stand for?

Comment: What exactly are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

`{/0}` is most likely a leftover from an template engine where you on one hand want to handle dynamic data and on the other hand want to have language control (i18n), consider this example:

```
var label = 'Hello {/0}';

var labelT = tempEngine(label, ['John Doe']);

function tempEngine(label, data) {
    return label.replace(/\{\/(\d+)\}/g, function(_, w) { return data[w]; });
}

console.log(labelT); // Hello John Doe
console.log(label); // Hello {/0}
```

It could ether be that the programmer forgot to parse the label against the dynamic data or that the template engine didn't find any match and therefore returned the key itself (`{/0}`)

anyway... This is just a guess. In your example I would guess that the text author wanted a image-icon where `{/0}` is